# after setVisible(true) frame loses location

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

I have an actionListener such as

```
menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

A seemingly straightforward code, except randomly the position of my frame is reset to (0,0) randomly.

This is done in the EDT thread therefore should be synchronized. Why does this occur?

Comment: Well I just wrote a program testing this. It isn't true for me.

Comment: Please consider creating and posting your [mcve]. Give us code that we can test and analyze.

Comment: It also works fine for me (frames stays at same location) using JDK8_45 on Windows 7. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. And give your version/platform so people running in that environment can confirm(?) a problem.

Comment: this was on JDK 1.6 on linux gnome ubuntu